# Counting number of shipments that contain at least two defective machines

Tags: combinatorics

I'll start off by admitting that this is a homework problem. **However, my main goal is to find out what kind of problem this is classified as and what concepts I need to learn to be able to solve similar ones.** I'm not just looking for an answer (although I would be glad to get one); **I need help by being pointed in the right direction.** Links to relevant articles and readings would be appreciated.

Problem:

> A shipment of 12 X-Ray machines includes 4 that are defective. In how
>   many ways can a hospital purchase 5 of these machines and receive at
>   least 2 of the defective machines?

I can only get as far as figuring out that there are 792 different ways to purchase 5 machines from the shipment of 12 (12 choose 5 is 792).

I realize this might be very easy for some people, but all I need is a little help (links and explanations is what I'm after, not just an answer). Thanks in advance!

Comment: I found two similar questions online but their answers are not too helpful
[1st link](http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Probability-and-statistics/Probability-and-statistics.faq.question.454589.html)
[2nd link](http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Permutations/Permutations.faq.question.144493.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose I want to pick $x$ bad machines, and $y$ good machines for a total of $x+y$ machines. First I pick the $x$ bad ones by choosing from the set of bad ones, so there's $\binom{4}{x}$ ways of picking the bad ones and $\binom{8}{y}$ ways to pick the good ones. Multiply the two to get the total number of ways. Since you want at least two defective ones, sum all the possible cases from 2 to 4.

Comment: Ok, so it would be the sum of (4Cx)*(12Cy) as I vary x from 2 to 4, right? But, do I also vary y so as to keep the sum x+y=5 ?
like this:
(4C2)*(12C3) + (4C3)*(12C2) + (4C4)*(12C1)
is this correct?

Comment: Do you happen to know what the name of the "rule" or concept you used to answer the question? I would very much like to read more about it... Thanks again!

Comment: wait, wouldn't I use (8Cy) instead of (12Cy) because there are only 8 "good" machines to pick from?

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought there were 12+4 machines. Thanks for the correction!